# ¿Cómo ejecutar una consulta MySQL con un script de python utilizando la biblioteca MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Intenté modificar un ETL pero he comprobado que el antiguo desarrollador ejecuta sus comandos directamente en la conexión (el ETL lleva unos años funcionando). Cuando intento hacerlo yo mismo me da error (porque mi compilador espera que lo haga desde un cursor).

```
from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
from etl.mysql.operations import add_column_if_not_exists
from etl.utils.array import chunks
from pprint import pprint


def add_column_exclude_from_statistics():
    with db as c:
        # Create new columns where exclude_from_statistics
        info("Creating column exclude from statistics")
        c.execute("""
            UPDATE orders
            INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.`Contact ID`
            IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit-pour-la-mission` 
                SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
            ELSE 
                SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0
            ;
        """)

def main():
    info("Table crm.orders")
    add_column_exclude_from_statistics()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pero me devuelve que `'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'`:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>py -m etl.task.crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics
2021-06-25 17:12:44.357297 - Connecting to database hozana_data...
2021-06-25 17:12:44.365267 - Connecting to archive database hozana_archive...
2021-06-25 17:12:44.365267 - Table crm.orders
2021-06-25 17:12:44.365267 - Creating column exclude from statistics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py", line 24, in main
    add_column_exclude_from_statistics()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py", line 12, in add_column_exclude_from_statistic
s
    c.execute("""
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Aqui esta lo que tenemos en `etl.mysql.connect`

```
import os
import MySQLdb

from etl.utils.logging import info

db_host = os.environ['DB_HOST']
db_port = int(os.environ['DB_PORT'])
db_user = os.environ['DB_USER']
db_password = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
db_name = os.environ['DB_NAME']
db_name_archive = os.environ['DB_ARCHIVE_NAME']

info("Connecting to database {}...".format(db_name))
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,
                     port=db_port,
                     db=db_name,
                     user=db_user,
                     passwd=db_password)
```

Es raro haber hecho eso, ¿no? ¿Es mi biblioteca `MySQLdb` la que no está actualizada?

Aqui estan las librerias relacionadas con MySQL. No encontré MySQLdb:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>pip list |findstr mysql
mysql                    0.0.3
mysql-connector-python   8.0.25
mysqlclient              2.0.3
```